# how could I press cancel on the select file window and have the program restart in powershell

Tags: forms, powershell

I have a button in my program that lets the user select a file from their computer however I would like to make it so when they press the cancel button it restarts the entire program.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated because I have been struggling with this for a while. This is what I have so far...

```
function SelectDrive($title){
  if($global:FirstDrive -eq $null){
  $DriveSelection = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
  $DriveSelection.Description = $title
# $DriveSelection.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
  [void]$DriveSelection.ShowDialog()  
  $global:FirstDrive = $DriveSelection.SelectedPath
    }
       else{
          removeAll 
          initVal
          $FillError.text = ""     
          $mainForm.controls.AddRange(@($StartUSB,$StartDualMedia,$SelectOne,$USBLabel,$2USBLabel))
          $mainForm.refresh()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$ClickedButton = $DriveSelection.ShowDialog()
if ($ClickedButton -eq 'Cancel') {
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
    Exit
}
```